# sql two-way join

Tags: sql, join

I have these two tables

table1:

[image: tbl1]

table2:

[image: tbl2]

and I want to get this table as a result of joining the two tables

[image: res]

Can you please help me with the right query?

10X

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

This will do it on ORACLE and SQL Server;

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.id, b.id), COALESCE(a.a, 0), COALESCE(b.b, 0)
FROM table1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 b 
  ON a.id=b.id
```

For MYSQL which is missing OUTER JOIN, you'll need to change it a bit;

```
SELECT a.id, COALESCE(a.a, 0), COALESCE(b.b, 0)
FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id
UNION
SELECT b.id, COALESCE(a.a,0), COALESCE(b.b, 0)
FROM table1 a RIGHT JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `full join` clause and check on `null` using any available function in your DBMS (like `isnull` or `coalesce`), e.g.:

```
select isnull(t1.id, t2.id), isnull(t1.a, 0), isnull(t2.b, 0)
from table1 t1
full join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

Comment: Thanks about the quick answer Kirill
it works like a charm for me!

Answer (score 0):

FULL OUTER JOIN solution has already been posted.

A version using UNION has also been posted for databases that do not support FULL OUTER JOIN (MySQL for example).

Better to modify the UNION query to use UNION ALL instead. The trick is to make sure a NOT NULL column from the 2nd outer joined table is NULL.

```
select table1.id table1.a, coalesce(table2.b,0) as b
  from table1
  left outer join table2 on table2.id=table1.id
union all
select table2.id coalesce(table1.a,0) as a, table2.b
  from table2
  left outer join table1 on table1.id=table2.id
 where table1.id is null
```

The UNION ALL solution may even be useful for databases that support FULL OUTER JOIN. I have seen Oracle give poor performance with a FULL OUTER JOIN, while the above UNION ALL solution worked like a charm.